# Case insesitive regex match with GoogleTest's regex matchers?

Tags: c++, regex, googletest, case-insensitive

## Question

I am looking for how to make a regular expression case insensitive, that works with GoogleTest's regex matchers (e.g. `ContainsRegex`).

I have tried unsuccessfully to prefix my expressions with `(?i)` or wrap them in `/`+`/i`:

```cpp
EXPECT_THAT("ExpreSSion", ContainsRegex("(?i)expression"));
EXPECT_THAT("ExpreSSion", ContainsRegex("/expression/i"));
```

**Does anybody know what regular expression engine GoogleTest uses, and if it supports case insensitive expressions?**

## Unpleasant workarounds

My workaround right now is lowering all characters before matching, but it makes the unit tests less readable and is IMO not good practice. I would like to test the actually produced data, not modifying it before testing it.

```cpp
EXPECT_THAT(toLower("ExpreSSion"), ContainsRegex("expression"));
```

Of course, in the examples above where the expression is known at compile time, one can explicitly match any case for each character, but it gets very unreadable

```cpp
EXPECT_THAT("ExpreSSion", ContainsRegex("[Ee][Xx][Pp][Rr][Ee][Ss][Ss][Ii][Oo][Nn]"));
```

This could be automated, but do we really have to go to those extents just to match a string ignoring case? Surely, this must be supported by the library out of the box?

```cpp
auto ContainsRegexCaseInsensitive(const std::string &expr)
{
    static const auto ignoreLetterCases = [](const std::string &expr) -> std::string 
    {
        // Replacinging letters with [<upper><lower>]
        // ...
    };
    return ContainsRegex(ignoreLetterCases("expression"));
}
EXPECT_THAT("ExpreSSion", ContainsRegexCaseInsensitive("expression"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My workaround is to provide matcher which converts argument to lower case.

```cpp
MATCHER_P(LowerCase, m, "Lower case " + DescribeMatcher<std::string>(m, negation))
{
    return ExplainMatchResult(m, boost::to_lower_copy(std::string(arg)), result_listener);
}
```

Now test is readable and looks ok:

```cpp
EXPECT_THAT("ExpreSSion", LowerCase(ContainsRegex("expression")));
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Y65MKed7c

Comment: I chose this workaround since it was the only that worked in our build system. However, I would have preferred the other solutions since they would be more flexible.

Answer (score 2):

According to google's [documentation](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/advanced.md#regular-expression-syntax),

> When built with Bazel and using Abseil, GoogleTest uses the RE2 syntax.

The latter has a way to specify case-insensitive search using *flags* (see [here](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax)):

```
(?flags)    set flags within current group; non-capturing
(?flags:re) set flags during re; non-capturing
```

```
    Flags
i   case-insensitive (default false)
```

Thus `(?i)` should work, if it does not you may rebuild the GoogleTest with Abseil.

Comment: `Otherwise, for POSIX systems (Linux, Cygwin, Mac), GoogleTest uses the POSIX extended regular expression` - since Bazel is not leading build system this means that it will not work in most cases.

Comment: Unfortunately, I could not get this to work in our build environment. I am sure it works for others.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of the expressions works by default.

For using RE2 expressions like "(?i)expression" you have to build GoogleTest with `-DGTEST_HAS_ABSL=ON` cmake option, otherwise it uses own implementation of the limited POSIX Extended Regular Expression syntax without flags. See [googletest/src/gtest-port.cc:726](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/2acd53824402affcf473b2355d7323047e660e86/googletest/src/gtest-port.cc#L726) for more details.

Comment: This sounds like a good option, but since I cannot control the GTest binary linked by my project, I cannot test it out. And thus unfortunately cannot set it as the answer. I will keep this in mind for the future though.